# Laravel eloquent and relationship

Tags: laravel, relational-database, eloquent

I have a code:

```
$response = $this->posts
    ->where('author_id', '=', 1)
    ->with(array('postComments' => function($query) {
        $query->where('comment_type', '=', 1);
    }))
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->limit($itemno)
    ->get();
```

And when I logged this query with:

```
$queries = \DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);
\Log::info($last_query);
```

In log file I see follow:

```
"select * from `post_comments` where `post_comments`.`post_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?) and `comment_type` <> ?"
```

Why is the question mark for comment_type in the query?

**Update #1:**

I replaced current code with following and I get what I want. But I'm not sure it is OK. Maybe exists many better, nicer solution.

```
$response = $this->posts
    ->where('author_id', '=', 1)
    ->join('post_comments', 'post_comments.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
    ->where('comment_type', '=', 1)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->limit($itemno)
    ->get();
```

Comment: What do you expect instead ? It's `PDO` binding.

Comment: I added '=' 1, but in log file I see = ?. I do not know why? :(

Comment: Are you asking why not `1` ?

Comment: Yes. It is my question :)

Comment: Where did you put this function and how are you calling the function ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. If you ask from which class or something like that, answer is: from Controller

Comment: From where you are using `$response = $this->posts...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the scene the [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is being used and it's the way that `PDO` does as a prepared query, for example check this:

```php
$title = 'Laravel%';
$author = 'John%';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE title like ? AND author like ? ";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title,$author));
```

In the run time during the execution of the query by `execute()` the `?` marks will be replaced with value passed `execute(array(...))`. `Laravel/Eloquent` uses `PDO` and it's normal behavior in `PDO` (PHP Data Objects). There is another way that used in `PDO`, which is named `parameter/placeholder` like `:totle` is used instead of `?`. Read more about it in the given link, it's another topic. Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons?rq=1).

**Update:** On the run time the `?` marks will be replaced with value you supplied, so `?` will be replaced with `1`. Also this `query` is the relational query, the second part after the first query has done loading the `id`s from the `posts` table. To see all the query logs, try this instead:

```php
$queries = \DB::getQueryLog();
dd($queries);
```

You may check the last two queries to debug the queries for the following call:

```php
$response = $this->posts
->where('author_id', '=', 1)
->with(array('postComments' => function($query) {
    $query->where('comment_type', '=', 1);
}))
->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
->limit($itemno)
->get();
```

### Update after clarification:

You may use something like this if you have setup relation in your `Posts` model:

```php
// $this->posts->with(...) is similar to Posts::with(...)
// if you are calling it directly without repository class
$this->posts->with(array('comments' =. function($q) {
    $q->where('comment_type', 1);
}))
->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->limit($itemno)->get();
```

To make it working you need to declare the relationship in your `Posts` (Try to use singular name `Post` if possible) model:

```php
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasmany('Comment');
}
```

Your `Comment` model should be like this:

```php
class Comment extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'post_comments';
}
```

Comment: Yea, but I get all records from database without comment_type restriction. As you can see. I added = 1, but I get all comment types from database. post_id is OK, but comment_type as it is ignored. I'm confused.

Comment: Can you instead ask what do you want to get from database and what you are getting? Show models and relationship for that.

Comment: In the run time the `?` will be replaced with `1`.

Comment: If I replaced [[ with(array('postComments' => function($query) { ]] with [[ whereHas('usersMessagesMapped', function($query) { ]] I get results as I want. but without columns from comments table :)